# Android webview leaks memory

Tags: android, memory

We're experiencing some problems with the android webview (<4.4 Kitkat)
Whenever we add a webview via xml some memory is leaked depending on our next action
- +- 5MB if we close the activity
- up to 200MB if we navigate to another activity, load some images and afterwards close the activity

The problem is that the memory is not leaked in the app
So our app doesn't crash with out of memory, but the devices available memory shrinks (a lot)
At first we thought this to be normal as android leaves the memory until it needs to reclaim it, but when we test a couple of times the device quickly runs out of memory and becomes extremely slow (only fix -> reboot)

When I take a memory dump and analyse it with MAT I can see our app has a heap of +-16MB so our activities are not leaked (I guess)

We've tried a lot of things, but all with no/minor changes:
- create a new WebView(ApplicationContext)
- call destroy & nullify references
- remove webview from viewGroup
- remove views of the webview
- webview.freememory (which gave us great hope when seeing the method name)
- destroyCache, setJavascript(false),...

Comment: Does it only happen if you add the webview via XML (asking because you explicitly mention this)? Does it depend on the rendered content? Can you show the rendered content?

Comment: same happens with new Webview, the problem exists even without loading content

Comment: Does the memory leak persist even when your app is terminated? Do you use multiple WebViews? If so, perhaps you could reuse one WebView to reduce the problem? If your Html is simple and you need a lot of WebViews, perhaps you could use a different html renderer?

Comment: the memory leak is still there when the app is killed. I even went desperate with System.exit tests etc... memory is lost
the content is very simple and in a next release we'll probably remove the webviews, with some custom views, but it's a shame that something like this is possible (leaking memory to the device)

Comment: Shameless plug: https://github.com/stefanhaustein/htmlview

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below code.. Hope it will useful.

```
       import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
       import android.webkit.WebSettings;
       import android.webkit.WebView;
       import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

       @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
       public class MyWebView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private WebView webView;
private WebSettings webSettings;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.website_view);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new DealerWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("url");

}

private class DealerWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}